# Access from swift to objective c function with a **void parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is mainly an "academic" question, so please don't ask "why do you need to do this" :-)

I have this objective c method, I'm not using ARC (I know that it leaks if I don't release the allocated string).
This method takes a pointer to a pointer to something in memory, then changes the pointed content to an NSMutableString.

```
+(void) writeString:(void **)var
{
    NSMutableString *aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"pippo %@", @"pluto"];
    *var = aString;
}
```

From Objective C I access it in this way and it works correctly

```
NSString *str;
[FLSwiftUtils writeString:&str];
NSLog(@"%@", str);  // prints pippo pluto
```

Now I want to access it from Swift in the same way, but I have problem with pointers.
I tried this way:

```
    var opaque = COpaquePointer.null()   // create a new opaque pointer pointing to null
    FLSwiftUtils.writeString(&opaque)
    println(opaque)
```

But it prints VSs14COpaquePointer (has 1 child), because `opaque` is a pointer and I don't understand how to deference it and access the pointed NSMutableString

If I try, then, to create an UnsafePointer starting from the opaque value:

```
    var str = UnsafePointer<NSMutableString>(opaque)
    println(str)
```

the println prints an empty line

I even tried this:

```
    var secondStr = AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSMutableString>(opaque.value)
    println(secondStr)
    println(secondStr.memory)
```

but it prints

VSs26AutoreleasingUnsafePointer (has 1 child)
__NSCFString

I think I am near the solution, but sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://ericasadun.com/2014/06/04/swift-using-addresses-for-nserror-and-void-pointers/

Comment: It doesn't help...I am using a void**, not a void* :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer on the Apple Forum (note: this code is FOR ARC)

```
+ (void)writeString:(void **)var
{
    NSMutableString *aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"pippo %@", @"pluto"];  // this is autoreleased by ARC

    *var = (void *)CFBridgingRetain(aString);   // send a retain, the release will be sent at the swift side
}
```

Then just release it into Swift like this:

```
    var opaque = COpaquePointer.null()   // create a new opaque pointer pointing to null
    TestClass.writeString(&opaque)

    var string = Unmanaged<NSString>.fromOpaque(opaque).takeRetainedValue()  // this function: creates an object, from the opaque pointer "opaque", take it's value and balance it with a release
    println(string)
```